# wait for animation to finish before resuming

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

i am animating a line using this function

```
 public static void Line(Canvas Drawing_Area, Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        Line line = new Line();
        Drawing_Area.Children.Insert(0, line);
        line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line.StrokeThickness = 3;
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        Random r = new Random();
        line.X1 = p1.X;
        line.Y1 = p1.Y - TopMargin;
        line.X2 = p1.X;
        line.Y2 = p1.Y - TopMargin;
        DoubleAnimation animation1 = new DoubleAnimation(line.Y1, p1.Y - TopMargin, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));
        DoubleAnimation animation2 = new DoubleAnimation(line.X1, p1.X, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));
        DoubleAnimation animation3 = new DoubleAnimation(line.Y2, p2.Y - TopMargin, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));
        DoubleAnimation animation4 = new DoubleAnimation(line.X2, p2.X, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation1, new PropertyPath("(Line.Y1)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation2, new PropertyPath("(Line.X1)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation3, new PropertyPath("(Line.Y2)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation4, new PropertyPath("(Line.X2)"));
        sb.Children.Add(animation1);
        sb.Children.Add(animation2);
        sb.Children.Add(animation3);
        sb.Children.Add(animation4);
        sb.Begin(line);
    }
```

how can i wait for the animation to finish before continuing (existing the function)

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard has a [Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event which you could subscribe to that tells you when the storyboard has finished running.

You could also use [Event Wait Handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332439(v=vs.71).aspx) to block the thread from continuing execution until your other event fires.